# How to run only delta changes in Terraform for new workspace

Tags: terraform

I'm using terraform in a CI/CD pipeline.

- When I open a pull request, I create a workspace named after the feature branch.
- Terraform creates all the resources with the workspace name attached to them so as to be unique.
- Once this is deployed to prod there is a cleanup step that destroys everything created by that workspace.

This works fine but recreating all the resources for every pull request soon will be unfeasible. Is there a way in Terraform to defer to the prod tfstate file so to plan only for the delta from this and their dependencies?

A simple example:

my prod tfstate has these resources

- 1 database(dbA)
- 2 schemas(dbA.schemaA,dbA.schemaB)
- 1 table (dbA.schemaA.tableA).

If I add one table(dbA.schemaB.tableB) in dbA.schemaB, I'd want terraform to plan for

- dbA
- dbA.schemaB
- dbA.schemaB.tableB

and not for

- dbA.schemaA
- dbA.schemaA.tableA

Comment: What is the overall objective here? If creating the new workspace is for acceptance testing, then you could use e.g. terratest for acceptance testing. Also, the workflow for acceptance testing would be in the declared modules and not the root module config where you would only be interested in the `plan` against the current state. Could you elaborate on the overall use case here?

Comment: the new workspace is to create dev resources in the dev accounts. Each PR creates its own set of resources so that multiple devs do not have their work conflicting with each other. Since we use a separate workspace then it's easy to clean up these with the destroy command. The problem is that as the number of resources increases we want to only create those that are relevant to the pull request i.e. the difference between what's in the feature branch and what's in the prod tfstate file

Comment: Unless you are deleting the state file on each run, that is exactly what happens. If everything is isolated and you add/delete stuff, Terraform will know what the difference is and plan will show that.

Comment: @MarkoE the statefile is created anew for each feature branch